# Autocomplete address field trigger to closest listed GEO location

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps-api-3

Right now, the code uses the browser's GEO location to determine, where the user is located, and calculates the distances from each location in the location list to the user. It sorts the list in the drop-down and requires the user to manually select a location there (this will be most of the time the shortest location on top of the sorted list).

By clicking on the button below the drop-down after the selection was made, a link will be executed that is associated with the user's selection.

I want to replace the code that automatically determines the location of the user with the Google API address field. The user should be required to type in an address, select one of the auto-populated options that is being displayed, and get forwarded to the link associated with the location closest to the selected address. The events that get triggered after selecting an address:

1. Distances are being calculated between the selected address and the locations in the location list
2. The closest location will be determined (the user has no say in this)
3. The link associated with the closest location will be executed (a href). The visual end result should be just one address field. I included the drop-down and button because I think this can be done with much of the underlying code, even though I have not been able to do so yet.

Thanks Ali for uploading the code into a fiddle:

https://fiddle.jshell.net/ali_soltani/5h283178/4/

Comment: Any constructive criticism on how to express my problem better or feedback where the problem lies?

Comment: As I commented on the duplicate question that you now deleted, you need to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the issue you are having. The code you post needs to be *Minimal* and your question should include a clear problem statement. Your snippet returns errors and cannot be used to reproduce the issue. Note that by creating a *Minimal* example and reducing your code to one problem, you are very likely to find the answer by yourself.

Comment: @MrUpsidown Updated. How would you express this problem differently/more minimally?

Comment: I created a [fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/ali_soltani/5h283178/4/) for understanding your problem, but it's unclear your problem for me and maybe other people. Please clarify your problem so we can help you better.

Comment: @AliSoltani Thanks a bunch, I updated the question.